# HttpClient.GetAsync returns weird result for some websites

Tags: c#, compression, httpclient

Please consider this simple Code:

```
private async void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = "It begins...";
    await DoAsync_Button3();
}

private async Task DoAsync_Button3()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://www.stackoverflow.com/");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    textBox1.Text = responseBody;
}
```

and the simple UI:

[image]

the problem is for some websites I got some weird result. for example: https://www.dotnetperls.com/

I got this result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I got weird result whereas `StatusCode` is 200. How do I determine where the problem is? Thanks

Comment: This code can be simpler by ‘using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    string html = client.DownloadString("http://example.com");
}’

Comment: @viveknuna `WebClient` was deprecated ages ago, there's absolutely no reason to use it in new code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-5.0#remarks

Comment: Take a look at the content-encoding header value for dotnetpearls. It shows you `br` for Brotli. This tells you, that the response is basically a compressed byte array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to decompress the response:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
{
    AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.All
});
string responseAsString = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://www.dotnetperls.com/");
Console.WriteLine(responseAsString);
```

If you are using .NET 5 or 6, you can use [`SocketsHttpHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.socketshttphandler?view=net-5.0) instead of `HttpClientHandler`.

Comment: Neither .NET Core 5 nor 6 exist, the products are called .NET 5 and .NET 6, respectively.

Comment: `HttpClientHandler` uses `SocketsHttpHandler` under the hood in .NET Core or newer versions. So there's no reason to provide it explicitly unless you need to make some specific setup for.